# How to make all select elements 15px wider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make all html "Select" 15px wider with CSS?

Not a static size because they're all different. I just want them 15px wider.

so something like this

```
select {
    width: +15px;
}
```

Comment: `padding-right: 15px`?

Comment: leave the width,  just add padding to it. Either left of right

Comment: Unless there is `box-sizing: border-box` set somewhere affecting selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
select {
     padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: _@j08691 that depends on the box-sizing property of the element. `box-sizing: content-box` lets the width only include content, padding and margin are not which leads to width being increased with padding._

__Edit: appearantly j08691 removed his previous comment. I've left my remark intact for completeness-sake.__

Comment: Not exactly the way I planned on doing it but I guess this works. Thanks
@DennisJamin, yes thats what i meant because padding just adds empty space, and i would like to have that being accessable too with the text. But for this example it works

Answer (score 0):

Consider using LESS CSS (http://lesscss.org/) This allows you to dynamically construct CSS files with variables, nesting, and other features.

Best part is, you can copy your CSS directly into LESS and it will compile just fine. Then you can gradually fine-tune everything to use the features of LESS.

Alternately, as others have suggested, use padding:

```
select {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
}
```

Of course, then you may run into problems if a certain select element has different padding requirements...

Comment: well i wanted to make it wider and also accessable with text or images. Padding adds empty space sort to say. But I guess for this example it works

Answer (score -1):

```
$("select").each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.width($this.width()+15);
});
```

Comment: i didnt downvote this, op asks for `CSS` but just to note: `jquery` **is** on the tags...